# Is that possible to generate a QR Code after done the transaction from the Authorize.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have created a small parking reservation application in ASP.NET (C#). In that i used a Authorize.net as a payment gateway. After clicked on the "PAY NOW" button its navigating to the Authorize.Net's payment site for further transaction after that nothing is in my hand, customer can fill the required details and he pay online and it will automatically generates a receipt of the transaction.
I need QR Code here...with the final receipt...is that possible?

Comment: Is the QR code a URL to the final receipt?

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of API's on the internet that can help you easilly and quickly do this. IE on Programmableweb: 
http://www.programmableweb.com/search/qr%20code

Additionally, NuGet has a number of libraries that you can add to your ASP.Net code to generate the QR Code on the server: 
http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=qrcode

Which one is best, depends on your needs, of course.

Comment: i know how to generate a QR code, but need to make it after the payment can be done. On the 3rd party site. After click on the "PAY NOW" button its navigate to the 3rd party site.

Comment: Aah, sorry :) are the any webhooks there that you can use in Authorize.net? I haven't looked deeply into their API's, but a quick question to them directly would answer that.

Comment: Thank you sir, no issues. please some buddy help.